# Is there a word that describes a conspicuous building that is out of its place?

Tags: adjectives, vocabulary, architecture

I remember that I read somewhere a comment about a building that is out of place, does not blend well with the surrounding architecture, and I think the author of that comment used a specific word to describe such building. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

His Royal Highness the Price of Wales in a 1984 [speech](https://www.princeofwales.gov.uk/media/speeches/speech-hrh-the-prince-of-wales-the-150th-anniversary-of-the-royal-institute-of) to the Royal Institute  of  British Architects described a proposed extension to the  National Gallery in London as

> a monstrous carbuncle on the face of a much-loved and elegant friend.

This could be the quote you have in mind.

Comment: Not exactly the quote, but rather the adjective 'monstrous'. The word is monstrosity, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an architectural term, but ***sore thumb*** is often used to describe buildings out of place:

startribune.com: Are contemporary homes cool kids, or sore thumbs?

ilovetheupperwestside.com: UWS Buildings that Stick Out Like Sore Thumbs

http://www.building.co.uk/: Strata tower: Southwark’s sore thumb

Also, ***intrusive***:

http://onlineathens.com/: The placement of the tower is intrusive when you balance the scale and placement of the buildings in the immediate vicinity of the tower. It sticks out like a sore thumb.

Answer (score 0):

An **anachronism** is:

> [something or someone that is not in its correct historical or chronological time, especially a thing or person that belongs to an earlier time](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/anachronism)

otherwise **eyesore**:

> [an ugly object or building](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eyesore)

Answer (score 0):

It is perhaps an ***incongruous*** building.

ODO:

> **[incongruous](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/incongruous)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> Not in harmony or keeping with the surroundings or other aspects of
>   something.
>
> ‘Critics argue the park itself is incongruous in a country where
>   around half the population of 130m lives below the poverty line.’